# Is a python subprocess allowed to use as many real threads as it can?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

So as we know, Python doesn't have real threading because of the `GIL` (unless you go the Cython route and detach) but i can't seem to find info or documentation on a usecase.

If from my python script i run a `Popen` with the commands `[dotnet test .....]` and that code supports the native C# threads and processes and all of that, will my Python subprocess execute as native C# and handle as many threads as the script needs to or is it locked behind 1 process and 1 thread?

Comment: "will my Python subprocess execute as native C#" - what do you mean here?

Comment: Any sub-process you launch with `Popen` will behave as it normally does. Python's threading model won't be inherited by a non-Python process when you launch it from within a Python process.

Comment: i mean as a normal c# process, meaning, will that C# process be able to spawn as many threads and processes as it needs?

Comment: @dano could you add this comment as an answer so i can close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any sub-process you launch with `Popen` will behave as it normally does. Python's threading model won't be inherited by a non-Python process when you launch it from within a Python process.